# Can a wall only be part-party? (England)

Tags: england-and-wales, real-estate

I own a semi-detached house 10m tall. A large garage on the detached side shares the bottom 2m of the wall. It belongs to the neighbours, who will build a house to replace the garage. Is the whole side wall considered a party wall, or only the bottom 2m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say all of the 10m wall based on the definition given at [s.20 of the Party Wall Act 1996](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/40/section/20?timeline=false):

> "party wall” means—
>
> (a) a wall which forms **part of a building** and stands on lands of different owners to a greater extent than the projection of any artificially formed support on which the wall rests; and
>
> (b) so much of a wall not being a wall referred to in paragraph (a) above as separates buildings belonging to different owners;

NB as per s.22(4), the 1996 Act extends to England and Wales only.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you - then I will edit my question to add that the wall is fully on my land, since it seems to make that definition not apply.

Comment: @GaspardB please don’t edit an answered question to make the answer inaccurate - ask another question instead

Comment: Ok, reverting, apologies.