# Can a wall fully on one's land be part-party?

Tags: england-and-wales, real-estate

I own a semi-detached house 10m tall. A large garage on the detached side shares the bottom 2m of the wall. It belongs to the neighbours, who will build a house to replace the garage. [In contrast to the previous question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64555/can-a-wall-only-be-part-party-england?noredirect=1&lq=1), the side wall is fully on my land, not astride the boundary. Is the whole side wall considered a party wall, or only the bottom 2m?

Additional information:

- There is no covenant or agreement between the two owners, the structures have been there for at least 40 years, and ownership has changed several times.
- Owner 2 would build on their side of the boundary, although it is unclear if they would build against the house wall (on the other side of the boundary line), or have the right to.

```
___
   \
H   \
o    |
u    |
s    |_______
e    |Garage |
_____|_______|
-----><-------
```

House is owner 1's, garage is owner 2's, house wall fully on owner 1's land

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a wall only be part-party? (England)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64555/can-a-wall-only-be-part-party-england)

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it refers to walls striding a property boundary, not fully to one side.

Comment: The text is *virtually identical* but for the addition of one sentence.

Comment: Yes, but it's an important sentence.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble even visualizing this...

Comment: I have added a diagram, if that makes it clearer.

Comment: @Gaspard **Q1**: Is there a covenant or some form of enforceable contract that allows part of the garage to be on Owner 1's land without trespass?  **Q2**: Does Owner 2 intent to build the new property (as per your previous post) on Owner's 1 land or remain entirely on his side of the boundary? **Q3**: Have you saught advice / information from the local Planning Officer?

Comment: This is not IMO a duplicate. The OP was asked to post a fresh question by mod DaleM.

Comment: I have added extra information. I was not aware planning could be asked for this kind of information, but if you think they could then I will, thank you.